# Grouping by two columns and then calculating the median

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where I want to calculate the median first flower date for each origin (native and exotic) per plot.

My end goal is to test if there is a significant difference in the median date of first flower among native and exotic species in warmed and ambient plots.

Here is a subset of my data:

```
dput(umbs_firstflower[8:16,])
structure(list(site = c("umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs", 
"umbs", "umbs", "umbs", "umbs"), plot = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", 
"A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3"), species = c("Sogi", "Sone", "Syla", 
"Cest", "Poco", "Popr", "Ruac", "Cest", "Dasp"), origin = c("Native", 
"Native", "Native", "Exotic", "Exotic", "Exotic", "Exotic", "Exotic", 
"Native"), state = c("ambient", "ambient", "ambient", "warmed", 
"warmed", "warmed", "warmed", "ambient", "ambient"), first.flower = c("248", 
"240", "227", "195", "169", "155", "156", "194", "185")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is an example of code I wrote to try and do this:

```
umbs <- umbs_firstflower %>% group_by(plot, origin) %>% summarize(mean.firstflw = mean(as.numeric(date))) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate `mean` or `median` ? There is no `date` column in your data. Do you need `mean(as.numeric(first.flower))` instead?

Comment: Yes, I should have said that. That number in the first.flower column is the Julian date. I want to calculate the median.

Comment: the data you've provided has "ambient" but no "warmed" values in `state`.  how to identify "warmed and ambient plots"?

Comment: I edited the example code to include both ambient and warmed states now.

Comment: thanks.  there is no warmed/exotic combo in the new data, is that intentional?  also, what is the significance test you plan to use to compare medians?

Comment: What is the origin of the dates. Maybe you can try. : `umbs_firstflower %>% 
  group_by(plot, origin) %>% summarize(mean.firstflw = median(as.Date(as.numeric(first.flower), origin = '1960-01-01'))) %>% ungroup()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of significance tests you might employ here, so I'll use one ([`kruskal.test()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kruskal.test.html)) to demonstrate the solution.  But note that [there is disagreement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81864/hypothesis-test-for-difference-in-medians-among-more-than-two-samples) as to the best way to test significant differences between medians for 3+ groups, so you may want to swap out this test for another one.

Steps:

1. Create a `grp` variable that matches the various combinations of interest across categorical columns.
2. `pivot_wider()` with the groups as columns of `first.flower` values.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df_wide <- 
  df %>%
  mutate(first.flower = as.numeric(first.flower),
         grp = case_when(
           origin == "Native" & state == "ambient" ~ "nat_ambi",
           origin == "Native" & state == "warmed" ~ "nat_warm",
           origin == "Exotic" & state == "ambient" ~ "exo_ambi",
           origin == "Exotic" & state == "warmed" ~ "nat_warm",
           TRUE ~ NA_character_
         )) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = 1:5, names_from = grp, values_from = "first.flower")

df_wide
# A tibble: 9 x 8
  site  plot  species origin state   nat_ambi nat_warm exo_ambi
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 umbs  A1    Sogi    Native ambient      248       NA       NA
2 umbs  A1    Sone    Native ambient      240       NA       NA
3 umbs  A1    Syla    Native ambient      227       NA       NA
4 umbs  A2    Cest    Exotic warmed        NA      195       NA
5 umbs  A2    Poco    Exotic warmed        NA      169       NA
6 umbs  A2    Popr    Exotic warmed        NA      155       NA
7 umbs  A2    Ruac    Exotic warmed        NA      156       NA
8 umbs  A3    Cest    Exotic ambient       NA       NA      194
9 umbs  A3    Dasp    Native ambient      185       NA       NA
```

3. Use the `%$%` `magrittr` pipe to run the significance test directly.

```r
 df_wide %$% kruskal.test(list(nat_ambi, nat_warm, exo_ambi))

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  list(nat_ambi, nat_warm, exo_ambi)
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 4.2667, df = 2, p-value = 0.1184
```